# Fixing Unknown http event format with AWS lambda and middy?

Tags: aws-lambda, middy

This is a test lambda. Where should the format be specified? Does middy now require event.requestContext.http.method specified somewhere?

```
import 'source-map-support/register';

import type { ValidatedEventAPIGatewayProxyEvent } from '@libs/apiGateway';
import { formatJSONResponse } from '@libs/apiGateway';
import { middyfy } from '@libs/lambda';

import schema from './schema';

const hello: ValidatedEventAPIGatewayProxyEvent<typeof schema> = async (event) => {
  return formatJSONResponse({
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    },
    message: `Hello ${event.body.name}, welcome to the exciting Serverless world!`,
    event,
  });
}

export const main = middyfy(hello);
```

The environment is

```
"@middy/core": "^3.1.0",
"@middy/http-cors": "^3.1.0",
```

With serverless: Framework Core: 3.21.0 (local) 3.21.0 (global)

Execution is via

> serverless invoke local --function hello  --path src/functions/hello/mock.json

```
"errorMessage": "[http-cors] Unknown http event format",
"errorType": "Error",
"stackTrace": [
    "Error: [http-cors] Unknown http event format",
    "    at httpCorsMiddlewareAfter (/Users/jrobens/NetBeansProjects/azuron/winpay/winpay-admin-api/node_modules/@middy/http-cors/index.cjs:82:19)",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@middy/http-cors support both REST (v1) and HTTP (v2) AWS events. Your test event doesn't fully comply the HTTP (v2) AWS event structure. Having it include `event.requestContext.http.method` will resolve this issue. Example in the AWS docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html.

Answer (score 1):

When running `serverless invoke local` the event generated does not have the httpMethod specified. This is with 'http' as the lambda event type.

When deployed it works fine, unit tests with jest also set this property.

Answer (score 0):

In your mock, you can add the `httpMethod` and set it to whatever you want: GET, POST, etc

Comment: On reading the code, there is a switch - if version is http then retrieve a token from this variable. The version wasn't formed properly with the context from invoke local missing parts. It can be reproduced in a straight test by skipping timestamps.